# UICollectionView didSelectItemAt not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am puzzled because It is just a simple thing but doesn't work.

This is my checked list before write question at here.

1. UICollectionViewDelegate is registered
2. There is nothing on above than UICollectionView from "Debug View Hierarchy"
3. `isUserInteractionEnabled` of UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCell is `true`
4. `isAllowsSelection` of UICollectionView is `true`

Is there anything else I should check out?

=====

```
class MyView: NibDesignable { // It's UIView with NibDesignableProtocol (https://github.com/mbogh/NibDesignable)
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        print("test - It's called.")

        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.collectionView.isAllowsSelection = true
    }
}

extension MyView: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath {
        print("test - It's not called")
    }
}
```

I pasted only the part relating to question because all of code is too long.

Comment: Can you show some steps that you followed. Code can also help.

Comment: can you post your code ??

Comment: Did you put `UICollectionViewDelegate` in your class definition `class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate`?

Comment: I added some code to question

Comment: @InderKumarRathore No. I implemented it on UIView. Does UICollectionViewDelegate work only with UIViewController?

Comment: It will work for everyone

Comment: Please cross verify your storyboard or xib to confirm that this class has properly assigned. Try removing the class from xib and re-adding it then later on connect outlets and finally run.

Comment: As the collection view is an outlet – aka designed in Interface Builder – why don't you make all the `setup` settings more conveniently (and reliably) in IB?

Comment: Any sub view of the cell, which receive touch event and do action ?

Comment: Have you found out an answer?

Answer (score 25):

This can happen if you have a gestureRecognizer in your custom cell.  this will override the didSelectItemAt delegate of the collectionView.

If this is your issue, then you can resolve it by identifying the gestureRecognizer and doing the following:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.someViewInMyCellTapped(_:)))
someViewInMyCell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Comment: This resolved my issue. I have Tap-, LongPress- and Pan-Gesture Recognizer configured, and use a UICollectionView (that can fade in and out) to choose things. Configuring "tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false" solved the issue and "didSelectItemAt" is called correctly by the delegate. Very useful answer.

Comment: Nice solution, but where can you put this code?  And if you used UIBuilder to add the GestureRecognizer, how do you identify it in code?

Answer (score 6):

`isUserInteractionEnabled` could be false on the `MyView` itself or on any of its parents.

Comment: I checked that it was `true`. And I test to add a UIButton to cell and tap it. It does work well.

Comment: There is a Content View over my collectionViewCell (which I can not remove in Xcode for some reason), which was UserInteractive Enabled. This was causing the didSelectItemAt to be not called for me.

Answer (score 4):

I changed the `isUserInteractionEnabled` property of the subviews of Cell to `false`. and it works.

Comment: That's it. Simple and great.

Answer (score 2):

In my case there was a problem with custom `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Despite the fact that the scroll and highlight worked for the collection, there was no cell selection. I had to use `cancelsTouchesInView` property of the recognizer.

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(myAction(_:)))
tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false // <- this helped
```

Also worth to check your collection view cell frame after screen loaded and views layout finished.

Comment: Yes, but WHERE do you put this code??

Comment: @JohnPitts I my view there was the custom `UITapGestureRecognizer` which overlays my `UICollectionView` and catches all touches.

Comment: OK, same for me.  I inserted cancelsTouchesInView = false as well, but now I'm unable to dismiss the keyboard!  damned if I do; damned if I don't.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's experiencing same issue as me with Simulator XR
try out other simulators. 
My didSelectItemAt method was never being called for some indexes when using XR simulator and index were random everytime I relaunched the simulator.
Using iPhone 6s simulator made it go away

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the cell is a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` and not the `UICollectionViewReusableView`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in Keyboard extension on My **BaseViewController**

```
extension NewBaseVC: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func initializeHideKeyboard(){
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(dismissMyKeyboard))

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissMyKeyboard(){
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

When I called the `initializeKeyboard()`, the `TapRecognizer` was fired. And the tap recognizer was overlapping with my collection view didSelectItemEvent.

Comment: Reminder: Dont use keyboard extension if your page has not any textfield.

Comment: Same for me, but the problem is, how do you dismiss a virtual keyboard then?  How can you dismiss/disable/uninsantiate the tapGestureRecognizer after the keyboard is dismissed?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting delegate inside

```
func awakeFromNib(){
 super.awakeFromNib()
 self.collectionView.dataSource = self
 self.collectionView.delegate = self }
```

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't work. And originally only the `didSelectItemAt` didn't work. but the items aren't presented after follow this. I guess it's because I don't use normal UIView.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it's because collectionView keep crazy reloading.

```
collectionView.reloadData
```

Only after end reload then I can interact with it.

Answer (score -1):

Also check parent view for `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

In my case `UITapGestureRecognizer` was on the on of the parent view for `UICollectionView`.

`UICollectionView` was scrolling ok, but didSelectItemAt was never called.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Turned out my contentView within the cell had user interaction enabled and was essentially blocking cell from registering the touch. Make sure to check all subviews for userInteractionEnabled = false.

Answer (score -2):

In storyboard CollectionView `Selectable` is uncheck for me. once you checkmark `Selectable` then Collectionview didSelectItemsAt will call.

1. Go to your storyboard
2. Select your CollectionView
3. checkmark `Selectable`

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I tried all solutions from this and it didn't help... I had to create new VC on the storyboard, in my case it was quite small